# Multiple if statements in a foreach loop

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach, laravel-blade

I have 3 reviews in my database but somehow it only shows 1 of the 3 star ratings as checked and the other 2 reviews star ratings are empty

```
@foreach($recensies as $recensie)

                <fieldset class="rating">
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == 5) checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == '4 and a half') checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == 4) checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == '3 and a half') checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == 3) checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == '2 and a half') checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == 2) checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == '1 and a half') checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == 1) checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
                    <input type="radio" disabled  @if($recensie->rating == 'half') checked="checked" @endif name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
                </fieldset>

@endforeach
```

Here is a picture to show you what I mean.

[image]

Comment: what are the rating values for these 3 recencies? Maybe you can output them with `$recensie->rating`? Anyway `2 and a half` as a rating value looks a bit cumbersome to me. Why you don't use `2.5` instead? So the value type would be `double` or `float` but not `string`.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a star rating system like this one: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating

then you would use just one input inside your @foreach:

```
<input id="input-id" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-size="lg">
```

and then call:

```
$('#input-id').rating('update', {{ $recensie->rating }});
```

Of course like Peh said you should use values like `2.5` instead of `2 and a half`.

Also you would want to have different ids for each input.